# iOS TableView on Scrollview Event Problem

Tags: ios, swift

I have a scrollview in a ViewController. The scrollview has a `UIScrollViewDelegate`.On upon that i am adding a Tableview like below:

```
self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
```

But when i am scrolling on tableview cells somehow the scrollview delegate is getting event, which is unexpected. 
What can i do to prevent that?

Comment: `UITableView` is the subclass of `UIScrollView`. Now on scrolling `tableView` is called then how it can be unexpected? It always happen. Probably you using components in wrong way, better if you explain your final requirement so that we can conc on it.

Comment: Do you really want both of them ScrollView and TableView be scrollable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITableView` is the subclass of `UIScrollView` and that is the reason you are getting calls to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` when you are scrolling the `cell`s.

You can not prevent this if you want to have the scrolling enabled for the `TableView`. I would suggest you check this condition inside your delegate method, for example:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard scrollView != self.tableView else {return}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal because UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. Thus you should check if scrollView != self.tableView then do what you want to do inside the scrollView delegate method.